# Why can't Pandas Remove Unknown Characters from Row Data?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

Hi everyone so i was scraping a footwear website and  have got all the links and images with their respective names and Brands.

I have saved them in an Excel file and i have also removed the unknown characters with the help of excel, but when i load it into pandas with jupyter Notebooks, The download stops at Number 83 as their is a \ in the name.

I tried using str.replace method but it gives me an EOL parsing Error

Here is my code and Also the respective Excel File For reference :)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

Final1 = pd.read_excel("VNV.xlsx")
Final1.index+=1

a = Final1.index.tolist()

Brand = Final1["Brand"].tolist()

Title = Final1["Title"].str.split().str.join(" ").tolist()

Images = Final1["Images"].tolist()

s = requests.Session()

for i,b,n,l in zip(a,Brand,Title,Images):
    r = s.get(l).content
    with open("Images//" + f"{i}-{b}-{n}.jpg","wb") as f:
              f.write(r)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-13d7c7daa564> in <module>
      3 for i,b,n,l in zip(a,Brand,Title,Images):
      4     r = s.get(l).content
----> 5     with open("Images//" + f"{i}-{b}-{n}.jpg","wb") as f:
      6               f.write(r)

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Images//83-ASICS-GEL-LYTE III OG "30TH ANNIVERSARY" \'WHITEFLASH CORAL\'.jpg'
```

EXCEL FILE ( Google Drive Link) :

[Excel File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iP07CFX7R6_o3M_W8CPN-sNPN2gFKKfu/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the answer my name had double quotes many times,

example in one Name: "s" f "g" "j"

so removed the quotes thanks to excel and all 250 images have been downloaded. :)